# How to initialize (and re-initialize) bootstrap-select via JavaScript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-select

I have a bootstrap modal with just one 'select' field, which I use for selecting colors or gender cuts or sizes for a selected clothing product on my beckend web app.

I get the data via ajax, returning a json array with {Id,Text,Val} for either color/gender or size (id differentiates color/gender/size)  and I clear out my select before adding the new options.

this works well with the standard HTML select..

```
<select id="productProperty" class="form-control" multiple></select>
```

Output with standard select:

[image: output with standard select]

but nothing works with boostrap-select

```
<select id="productProperty" class="form-control selectpicker" multiple></select>
```

Output with bootstrap select:

[[image: Output with bootstrap select[2]]

here's my ajax call

```
     $.ajax({   url: 'theUrl',
                type: "GET",
                data: { requiredInput: 'that' }
            }).done(function(response) {

                $("#productProperty").empty();
                var selectHtml = "";
                $.each(response.data, function(index, item) {
                  selectHtml += "<option value='" + item.Id + "' " + disabled_ + ">" + item.Name + "</option>";
                });

                $("#productProperty").html(selectHtml);
                $("#productProperty").selectpicker('refresh');

            });
```

I have  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker() on my layout (MVC) file as I do with datepicker and datatables

How can I work this out with bootstrap-select ?.
Thanks.

Comment: Don't you want to keep the kind of select where you can see all of the options at once, like the one in the first picture? If you want to do that, you cannot do that with the bootstrap-select plugin

Comment: `$("#productProperty").selectpicker('render');` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(select).selectpicker('refresh');
```

Answer (score 1):

**jQuery $.each syntax error**

Original HushdMap Access

```
$.each(response.data, function(index, item) {
    selectHtml += "<option value='" + item.Id + "' " + disabled_ + ">" + item.Name + "</option>";
});
```

Success HushdMap Access

```
$.each(response.data, function(index, item) {
    selectHtml += "<option value='" + index + "' " + disabled_ + ">" + item + "</option>";
});
```

P.S. DevTools console step by step checking ...

```
console.log(disabled_);
```

my console

> Uncaught ReferenceError: disabled_ is not defined

your console?

> disabled

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just build the whole thing via jQuery?

First, make the select dropdown:

```
var html = "";
html += '<select id="productProperty" class="form-control selectpicker" multiple>';
```

Then go through your ajax:

```
 $.ajax({   url: 'theUrl',
            type: "GET",
            data: { requiredInput: 'that' }
        }).done(function(response) {

            $.each(response.data, function(index, item) {
              html += "<option value='" + item.Id + "' " + disabled_ + ">" + item.Name + "</option>";
            });
        });
```

Then close tags:

```
html += "</select>";
```

Append it, and you should be all good.

```
$(".container").append(html);
```

Comment: I did it that way but still doesn't show the options. The same code works with the standard select (by just removing the 'selectpicker' class )